# sort HTMLCollection by date

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an HTMLCollection of div that i would like to sort by date and it return an error that the.sort on my collection is not a function

```
const date = new Date();
const stages = document.getElementsByClassName("cadre-affiches");

for (let i = 1; i < stages.length; i++) {
stages[i].dateStage = new Date(stages[i].getAttribute("date"));
if (stages[i].dateStage < date) {
  stages[i].remove();
}
};

let sorted = stages.sort((a,b) => b.dateStage - a.dateStage);

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: stages needs to be an array, see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort. The getElementsByClassName() method returns an HTMLCollection.

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByClassName` return `HTMLCollection` which is an `Object`. You can convert it to an `Array` to access the `sort` function.

Replace this line of code.

```
let sorted = stages.sort((a,b) => b.dateStage - a.dateStage);
```

to this

```
let sorted = Array.from(stages).sort((a,b) => b.dateStage - a.dateStage);
```